# Is there any liquid to stop leakage inside pipe or fitting

Tags: thermostat

i want to ask i have doubt there is a leakage in UPVC pipes or fittings but i am not able to find out this leakage is there any liquid to stop the leakage ( like i just put some kind of liquid inside pipe and leakage should be stopped) i need this liquid name? all pipes and fittings underground.

Comment: Is this a pressurized pipe (like water main) or is it a drain pipe (unpressurized)?

Comment: its UPVC Underground network (unpressurized) bell-and-spigot ends but i want to fix this problem othervise i need to broke all tieling work & Excavate the all area and expose the all network but leakage is very small.

Comment: This might be an odd question, but if it's truly underground, how do you know that it is leaking? Is there a source of the water?

Comment: yes there is drop of water because we already make gravity leak test And backfill that area with approved leak test for underground network and after that we install above ground now we have to make one more gravity leak test now water after 2 hours going down 15cm so thats why i ask this question?

Comment: If there is any type of liquid to stop this leakage othervise big loss for me and i heard this new there is one chemical to insert the hole network to to stop miner leakage ..

Answer (score 1):

The honest answer is no.

There are things that will fix your problem, but they will cause more harm at the end.

It is like a pill that will only fix the problem, but have no side effects.

Your list of wants is long:

You want something that is liquid inside the pipe, find the leak inside of the pipe, and then dry inside of the pipe.

You are also looking for something that will attach and block to the pipe at the hole, but not attach to rough spots or connectors in the pipe.

It will also not harden around whatever is at the end of the pipe.

There is nothing that will only do what you want.

Your list of fixes is short:

The solution is to either put a smaller piece of pipe in the one you think leaks, and use that instead, or trace the entire pipe to find the leak.

Comment: its UPVC Underground network (unpressurized) bell-and-spigot ends  but i want to fix this problem othervise i need to broke all tieling work & Excavate the all area and expose the all network but leakage is very small.

Comment: Tile work, I would try almost anything to avoid that also. The only thing I know that will stick to UPVC is UPVC glue. A smaller pipe, wait until the leak causes damage to the wall, that you can see, or open wall.   Crazy idea, almost insane. Pull a plastic string 2 times the length of the pipe through it, tie a rag in the center, with window cleaner. Pull it back and forth a few times to clean the inside of the pipe.

Comment: Then tie on a new rag, soaked in upvc pipe cleaner through, then a final rag, soaked in upc glue, slowly through the pipe. Maybe, just maybe the glue will melt the spot with the hole. Most likely the rag or the string will get glued to the pipe, blocking it completely. You could try this, just with the glue after the 1st cleaning, a few times. This is a crazy idea, it is best to not try it. I only mention it because it came to my mind. Pull too slow, and the glue will melt the pipe, and the rag will then complete block the pipe, too fast and no glue will cover the leak. Pull without enough glu

Comment: Pull without enough glue put in the pipe before the rag, it will only get the first few meters. Pull second time before glue dries, lots of melting. Seems like only more problems with this thought, and all pipe could need replacing, and all tile opened. Bad Idea. I have them sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Much later, I see a product called Pipefuze on the Web.  I have not tried it yet, but am considering it.  About $900 for a kit with pump, sealant, etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).